# Per-user GPU usage on a Linux machine (CUDA)

Tags: nvidia, monitoring, gpu

I use the CUDA toolkit to perform some computations on my Nvidia GPUs. How can I see the per-user GPU usage on a Linux machine (CUDA)?

`nvidia-smi` doesn't seem to contain information:

[image]

I am aware I could use the PIDs to retrieve the user ids, but I'd prefer to have a single command.