# How to log GPU load?

Tags: logs, monitoring, gpu

I wonder how to log GPU load. I use Nvidia graphic cards with CUDA.

**Not a duplicate: I want to log.**

Comment: Already answered here: > http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda

Comment: @monsune Thanks, it looks like the other question is about real-time monitoring while mine is about logging. I'll try to Python code, that might do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all there. You just didn't read carefuly :) Use the following python script which uses an optional delay and repeat like iostat and vmstat:

https://gist.github.com/matpalm/9c0c7c6a6f3681a0d39d

You can also use nvidia-settings:

> nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q useddedicatedgpumemory

...and wrap it up with some simple bash loop or setup a cron job or just use watch:

> watch -n0.1 "nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q
>   useddedicatedgpumemory"'

Comment: Thanks, eventually I am using: `while true; do nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv >> gpu_utillization.log; sleep 1; done`. I wish the format was truly csv :)  and I haven't found a way to obtain the [per-user GPU usage on a Linux machine (CUDA)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248814/16704).

Comment: As a side note, `nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization` is giving me this error: `ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run nvidia-settings --help for usage information.`. Maybe `nvidia-smi` changed.

Comment: Right. That's the simple bash loop i mentioned above ;) There are so many ways to skin this cat and it's a nice task, too. Thanks for that useful per-user GPU usage link BTW. Not sure about that error yet but it is solvable most likely. I'm on 352.63 and it works fine. Do you run that as root? If so, try as user and it should work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which `nvidia-smi` version do you use? (I use 352.63)

Answer (score 17):

use

```
nvidia-smi dmon -i 0 -s mu -d 5 -o TD
```

then you can easily dump this into a log file.
this is the gpu usage for device 0 sampled at an interval of 5 seconds

```
 #Date       Time        gpu    fb  bar1    sm   mem   enc   dec   pwr  temp
#YYYYMMDD   HH:MM:SS    Idx    MB    MB     %     %     %     %     W     C
 20170212   14:23:15      0   144     4     0     0     0     0    62    36
 20170212   14:23:20      0   144     4     0     0     0     0    62    36
 20170212   14:23:25      0   144     4     0     0     0     0    62    36
```

see the man page for details on flags.

In case of multi-GPU environment, one can remove `-i 0` in the above command to log all GPUs.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: It's okay now,I hope

Answer (score 12):

You can use (tested with `nvidia-smi 352.63`):

```
while true; 
do nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv >> gpu_utillization.log; sleep 1; 
done.
```

The output will be (if 3 GPUs are attached to the machine):

```
utilization.gpu [%]
96 %
97 %
92 %
utilization.gpu [%]
97 %
98 %
93 %
utilization.gpu [%]
87 %
96 %
89 %
utilization.gpu [%]
93 %
91 %
93 %
utilization.gpu [%]
95 %
95 %
93 %
```

[Theoretically](https://gridforums.nvidia.com/default/topic/232/monitoring-assessment-tools/capture-vgpu-performance-data-in-csv-format-using-nvidia-smi/), you could simply use `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv --loop=1 --filename=gpu_utillization.csv`, but it doesn't seem to work for me. (the flag `-f` or `--filename` logs the output to a specified file).

To log more information:

```
while true; 
do nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu,utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used --format=csv >> gpu_utillization.log; sleep 1; 
done
```

outputs:

```
utilization.gpu [%], utilization.memory [%], memory.total [MiB], memory.free [MiB], memory.used [MiB]
98 %, 15 %, 12287 MiB, 10840 MiB, 1447 MiB
98 %, 16 %, 12287 MiB, 10872 MiB, 1415 MiB
92 %, 5 %, 12287 MiB, 11919 MiB, 368 MiB
utilization.gpu [%], utilization.memory [%], memory.total [MiB], memory.free [MiB], memory.used [MiB]
90 %, 2 %, 12287 MiB, 11502 MiB, 785 MiB
92 %, 4 %, 12287 MiB, 11180 MiB, 1107 MiB
92 %, 6 %, 12287 MiB, 11919 MiB, 368 MiB
utilization.gpu [%], utilization.memory [%], memory.total [MiB], memory.free [MiB], memory.used [MiB]
97 %, 15 %, 12287 MiB, 11705 MiB, 582 MiB
94 %, 7 %, 12287 MiB, 11540 MiB, 747 MiB
93 %, 5 %, 12287 MiB, 11920 MiB, 367 MiB
```

Comment: with 352.79 I just get 'not supported'utilization.gpu [%]
[Not Supported]
[Not Supported]
utilization.gpu [%]
[Not Supported]
[Not Supported]
utilization.gpu [%]
[Not Supported]
[Not Supported]
utilization.gpu [%]
[Not Supported]
[Not Supported]
utilization.gpu [%]
[Not Supported]
[Not Supported]

Comment: @aquagremlin this may be due to the GPU model. http://askubuntu.com/q/701222/44876

Comment: indeed. I figured out the best I can do is logging performance state with this           nvidia-smi -l 1 --query --display=PERFORMANCE --filename=gpu_utillization.log

Comment: wow, that is it, works in headless mode as well (when x driver is not used)