# Why nvidia-smi's GPU so rarely reaches 100%?

Tags: nvidia, monitoring, gpu

I have [logged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252590/16704) the GPU utilization of my 3 GPUs (GeForce GTX Titan X) for 5 days with `nvidia-smi`, every 10 seconds. The GPUs were all being utilized: I count 1307 occurrences of `99 %` while only 8 occurrences of `100 %`. Why nvidia-smi's GPU so rarely reaches 100%?

[image]

[image]

Another example from https://openai.com/blog/infrastructure-for-deep-learning/:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: It highly depends on what your computations/datasets are, and the load-balancing between the GPUs. Not to mention your hardware which could be a factor. But it seems a little bit curious to want to have _exactly_ 100% of used RAM.

Comment: @Paradox 100% GPU utilization, not RAM.

Comment: @FrankDernoucourt Yes, you are right, my bad. But still, RAM or GPU utilization, it's the same: having _exactly_ 100% is difficult unless everything is optimized to the very last bit and purely theoretical. When seeing 98 or 99%, it already seems pretty impressive for multiple components on a single machine. That's why your numbers do not seem explicitly showing a problem to me, depending on what's running on your GPUs.