# List the GPU utilizations for each screen

Tags: gnu-screen, monitoring, gpu

How can I list all screens launched with `screen` along with their GPU utilizations? (`screen -ls` gives the lists of screens but not their GPU utilization)

By GPU utilization of a screen, I mean the sum of GPU utilizations of the processes that was launched in the screen.

The GPU are used via the CUDA toolkit to perform computations. All GPUs are Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: The program `screen` has not much to do with GPUs. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @joepd Processes launched during a screen may use GPUs. I am trying to list the GPU uses per screen. By GPU utilization of a screen, I mean the sum of GPU utilizations of the processes that was launched in the screen.

Comment: Do you have a method of observing GPU utilizations of a list of processes? If so, please specify what already works. If not, that should be your question ;)

Comment: @joepd ah, good point, that's indeed it a prerequisite: [Per-user GPU usage on a Linux machine (CUDA)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248814/16704). Hard to believe it's not straightforward :-( I forgot I hadn't found a solution for that one.